# String and ascii values

Tags: c++, string

In this piece of code if i run a for loop to know elements stored inside the array `c` I get output as `1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0`.

The input is `abc`. Why it does it give `1 1 1` instead of `0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0`?

```
int c[26]={};
cin >> s;
len = s.length();
for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++ ){
    c[s[i] - 'a'] ++ ;
}
```

Comment: Why would it give 0 1 2? You're making a wrong assumption about what this code does.

Comment: There's one 'a', one 'b' and one 'c'. Why do you expect 0,1,2 ?

Comment: So what is the concept of this code .will you explai it or link me to some similar question

Comment: It calculates the number occurences of every character in the string, assuming that the string only consists of lower case letters. Otherwise, undefined behavior may result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is basically counting the number of letters in a string. The count is stored in the array `c` where the index represents the letter index in the alphabet. So `a` is `0`, `b` is `1`, `c` is `2` and so on.

So for `abc` the correct input is indeed `1 1 1`, due to the fact that there's 1 `a`, 1 `b` and 1 `c`. Your `0 1 2` would represent a string with 1 `b` and 2 `c`s.

Answer (score 1):

Your `c` array is a histogram of the characters read. Your output is saying you read 1 'a', 1 'b' and 1 'c'. Try `c[s[i] - 'a'] = s[i] - 'a';`

Comment: I tried the code with abcdefghia as input and i am getting 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 11 followed by zerors.Why 2 at third place when c is just once?

Answer (score 0):

```
s[i] - 'a'
```

That is returning 0, 1 and 2. But

```
c[s[i] - 'a'] ++ ;
```

Is always increasing 1 each occurrence of C[] which at the beginning was initializing with all zeros. For that reason you get all 1s in your output.

Try

```
c[s[i] - 'a'] = s[i] - 'a'
```

Comment: I ran the code with abcdefghia as input i am getting 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 followed by zeroes.Can you explain why i am getting 2 at third place for c is repeated just once

Comment: try declaring s at the beginning -->  string s;